# $window.open throwing $apply error on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, window.open

I have a function that basically consists of

```
var onclick = function() {
   $window.open(url, "_blank", 'location=yes');
}
```

On Firefox, though, when I click I get:

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

This is a pretty common problem, usually solved by putting the whole thing in a `$timeout()` block.

Except, calling `$window.open()` from a timeout activates the popup blocker!  I need some way of accomplishing the same thing, without exiting the thread.

Comment: How are you calling `onclick`. I'm guessing by the name its a click handler. May be cause you quickly typed it up for the question but there is no `$scope` so i assume angular is not handling the click? So are you manually calling `$apply` somewhere before calling this?

Comment: This usually happens when u start mixing angular and non-angular code together. http://plnkr.co/edit/tyj1K0DMryBejH0upDPU?p=preview may this will help u a little to understand when you chould call $apply.

Comment: FYI this appears to be due to a known issue in Firefox. Details here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10083 / https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1127236

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var onclick = function() {
  if($scope.$root.$$phase) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $window.open(url, "_blank", 'location=yes');
    },0,false);
  } else {
    $window.open(url, "_blank", 'location=yes');
  }
}
```

However, you have duplicity of $window.open args. You can make your code better doing:

```
var onclick = function() {
  var windowArgs = [url, "_blank", 'location=yes'];

  if($scope.$root.$$phase) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $window.open.apply($window,windowArgs);
    },0,false);
  } else {
    $window.open.apply($window,windowArgs);
  }
}
```

Comment: $timeout( function() { $window.open(...) }, 0,false); - it's work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
window.open()
```

remove $window

Use like:

```
window.open(url,target,"status=no,height="100px",width="100px",resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no);
```

Javascript window

Comment: That would introduce a global variable negating any benefit from angulars injection system, making testing great fun.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. There is the same issue like with using $window